# How do I add a simple multiplication formula to excel user input box?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question which I believe requires a bit of coding but I could be wrong.

I am trying to create a pdf catalog using excel and publisher together. Publisher uses the data in excel spreadsheet to automatically create a catalog.

- I would like to create a user input box for clients to type a quantity (with a default value of "0").
- I would like to add a formula to my user input box so that whatever number the client enters as quantity, it will multiply that value by the price in cell "C1".
- I would like the default to be 0 in the input box.
- If the user inputs (e.g. 5) then I would like to multiply that value by C1 (e.g. $2.99) and then display the result in a separate cell (e.g. E1)

If there is an easier way to incorporate quantity x price using excel and user input for quantity please let me know.

Than

Comment: Are you wanting to replace, in the input box, the user-input value with their value multiplied by cell C1's value?  (This would be really annoying to the user.)  Or just to use (elsewhere) their value multiplied by cell C1's value.  (This is quite easy and a normal thing for a form to do.)

Comment: I would like the default to be 0 in the input box. If the user inputs (e.g. 5) then I would like to multiply that value by C1 (e.g. $2.99) and then display the result in a separate cell (e.g. E1).

Comment: @justinpees - just my 2 cents here; time to get on the Web bandwagon.  Nobody likes pdf's.  You can create this functionality in a webpage/html very easily.  See twitter bootstrap or Google MDL and just very basic javascript.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple `UserForm` with a *TextBox* and *Label* with code as below

*updated for your new comment to dump to e1*

Code uses cells on first worksheet.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Me.Label1 = CLng(Me.TextBox1) * Sheets(1).[c1].Value
Sheets(1).[e1].Value = Me.Label1
End Sub
```

[[image]

[image]

Comment: How does a VBA userform translate to Adobe pdf?

Comment: Im not clear on what you mean? OP explicitly asked for a userform to prompt the user for an entry, the code writes back to the sheet.

Comment: `I am trying to create a pdf catalog using excel and publisher together.`  I dunno, but it sounds like some kind of pdf result he is looking for.  Anyways, I've given this question way too much attention.  Take care...

Comment: Actually now that you brought that up Ron, I believe the only way to make this work in pdf form is to "replace" the input with the calculated input when the user hits the return key.

Answer (score 0):

You enter the formula in the result cell.  The price cell is set by you and should not be editable by the user.  The quantity cell should be edited by the user.

The result cell would have a formula like '=A1*B1'.  Really trivial actually.

[image]

Comment: why the downvote?  Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: There isn't a way to just convert a cell to a user input when exported to pdf?